# Hide Keyboard in iOS by using Tabris

Tags: ios, eclipse

is there an option to remove the keyboard from screen on iOS ? I use Tabris (http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/) and Java in this context.

My problem is that i use two textfields to enter a user/passwort combination. After I filled these textfields and press a button to continue the keyboard from iOS is always shown but I want that the keyboard no longer appears. Only after I click somewhere then the keyboard disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Tabris, you can "open" the keyboard programmatically by setting the Focus on a Control which uses the keyboard (like org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text ).
To hide the keyboard, just set the Focus to a Control which does not require a keyboard, like the parent composite of your Textfield.

In your case I would add al line to the SelectionListener of your Button to set Focus on the Parent of your Textfields, then start the Login procedure.

Here is some code to play and understand the Focus mechanism:

```
public class FocusTest implements EntryPoint {

public int createUI() {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
    shell.setMaximized(true);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().applyTo(shell);
    createContent(shell);
    shell.open();
    //while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    //  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    //      display.sleep();
    //  }
    //}
    return 0;
}

private void createContent(final Composite parent) {
    Button buttonSingleText = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonSingleText.setText("Focus on SingleText");
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).applyTo(buttonSingleText);

    Button buttonMultiText = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonMultiText.setText("Focus on MultiText");
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).applyTo(buttonMultiText);

    Button buttonNoFocus = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonNoFocus.setText("Loose Focus");
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).applyTo(buttonNoFocus);

    final Text singleText = new Text(parent, SWT.SINGLE);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).applyTo(singleText);

    final Text multiText = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER).applyTo(multiText);

    buttonSingleText.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            singleText.setFocus();
        }
    });
    buttonMultiText.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            multiText.setFocus();
        }
    });
    buttonNoFocus.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            parent.setFocus();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the example but the button for loose focus not work correctly. I tried this in the iPhone Simulator and the keyboard won´t hide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set UITextField delegate and add the following method there?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```